# navigation bar positioning top left corner

Tags: css, uinavigationbar

I am new to HTML CSS and JS and am creating a website and have had a problem for a few days now, I have created a navigation bad to switch between pages but i cannot seem to position it correctly in the top left corner I was wondering if anyone could help. I would like it to be positioned exactly in the top left corner but it seems to be out of position. I have tried many solutions but cant seem to get the result i am looking for.

```css
body {
        margin-left: 50px;
        margin-right: auto;
        background-color:     
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        width: 800px;
    
        }
    
        .topnav {
        background-color: #333;
        overflow: hidden;  

        }
    
    
        .topnav a {
        float: left;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 20pt;
        }
    
    
        .topnav a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
        }
    
    
        .topnav a.active {
        color: white;
        }
    
        html {
        background: url(UFC.jpg);
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;   
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="website.CSS">
     </head>
     <body>
        <div class="topnav">
       `enter code here` <a class="active" href="home.html"><u>Home</u></a>
        <a href="topfighters.html"><u>Top Fighters</u></a>
        <a href="bestknockouts.html"><u>Best Knockouts</u></a>
        <a href="contactpage.html"><u>Contact Page</u></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/ItsssOwen">
        <img src="twitter%20link.png"  width="42" height="32" border="0">
        </a>
        </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the position of an element with css position, specifying top, left, right, bottom position (only one x and one y are needed).

```css
body {
        margin-left: 50px;
        margin-right: auto;
        background-color:     
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        width: 800px;
    
        }
    
        .topnav {
        background-color: #333;
        overflow: hidden;  
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        }
    
    
        .topnav a {
        float: left;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 20pt;
        }
    
    
        .topnav a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
        }
    
    
        .topnav a.active {
        color: white;
        }
    
        html {
        background: url(UFC.jpg);
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;   
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="website.CSS">
     </head>
     <body>
        <div class="topnav">
       `enter code here` <a class="active" href="home.html"><u>Home</u></a>
        <a href="topfighters.html"><u>Top Fighters</u></a>
        <a href="bestknockouts.html"><u>Best Knockouts</u></a>
        <a href="contactpage.html"><u>Contact Page</u></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/ItsssOwen">
        <img src="twitter%20link.png"  width="42" height="32" border="0">
        </a>
        </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

But your problem is that you specified a

```
 margin-left: 50px;
```

for your body, causing the elements to move 50 px to the right, and you can reach it by deleting it:

```css
body {
        background-color:     
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        width: 800px;
    
        }
    
        .topnav {
        background-color: #333;
        overflow: hidden;  

        }
    
    
        .topnav a {
        float: left;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 20pt;
        }
    
    
        .topnav a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
        }
    
    
        .topnav a.active {
        color: white;
        }
    
        html {
        background: url(UFC.jpg);
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;   
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="website.CSS">
     </head>
     <body>
        <div class="topnav">
       `enter code here` <a class="active" href="home.html"><u>Home</u></a>
        <a href="topfighters.html"><u>Top Fighters</u></a>
        <a href="bestknockouts.html"><u>Best Knockouts</u></a>
        <a href="contactpage.html"><u>Contact Page</u></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/ItsssOwen">
        <img src="twitter%20link.png"  width="42" height="32" border="0">
        </a>
        </div>
     </body>
</html>
```